# Group mysql results by type - but only in a certain order

Tags: mysql, group-by

Background information: I am working at a little, private pingdom.com clone.

I have a table with status checks if a website is available or not and the date of the check of course. Some of them have the status "ok", some "not ok". Now I want to group the rows by status, but only the one in the same "timeframe".

Example:

```
id   status   timestamp
1    ok       1234
2    ok       1235
3    not ok   1236
4    ok       1237
```

The query should make three groups with the ID's 1-2, 3 and 4. In the end I want do display that the tested site was 2 hours online, 1 hour offline and then 1 hour online again. Of course i could filter the results afterwards but I thought that this would be very inefficient with a large data set.

I have absolutely no idea where to start, because you can't group only by status. A short help for the search term would be sufficient, english is not my first language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT min( timestamp ) from_timestamp, 
       max( timestamp ) to_timestamp,
       max( timestamp) - min( timestamp ) + 1 how_long,
       min( id ) from_id,
       max( id ) to_id,
       status
FROM (
    SELECT t.id,
           t.timestamp,
           if(@last_status = status, @group, @group:=@group+1) group_number,
            @last_status := status as status
    FROM table1 t
    CROSS JOIN (
       SELECT @last_status := null, @group:=0
    ) as init_vars
    ORDER BY t.timestamp 
) q
GROUP BY group_number
ORDER BY from_timestamp
```

demo: --> http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2aa1e/10

Comment: Really great! I think I might need some time to implement it, but the demo works, so thank you!